# i want to retrieve all data from the above 4 tables, based on property id

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically this site for property agent,

i want to retrieve all columns from the below 4 tables, based on property id.

short descrip:
wp_tm_properties  -> Will add my main property name(id,property_name)

wp_tm_sub_properties -> Will add my sub-property based on main property

wp_tm_tenants --> Will add my tenants name and other related information based on property & property

wp_tm_reports --> Will add my tenants report based on property and sub property

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_tm_properties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_tm_sub_properties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_property_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_tm_tenants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ten_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ten_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ten_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ten_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ten_sdate` date NOT NULL,
  `ten_edate` date NOT NULL,
  `contract_form` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_tm_reports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ten_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rep_sdate` date NOT NULL,
  `rep_des` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rep_action` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `rep_edate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rep_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4
```

Comment: you should show your effort, means what you've done so far to solve this ?

Comment: if possible provide sample data(to add rows to all 4 tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use joins to connect the tables on the related columns:

```
select * 
from `wp_tm_properties` p
join `wp_tm_sub_properties` sp on p.`id` = sp.`prop_id`
join `wp_tm_tenants` t on t.`prop_id` = p.`id` and t.`sub_property_id` = sp.`id`
join `wp_tm_reports` r on r.`prop_id` = p.`id` and r.`sub_property_id` = sp.`id`
```

This uses`INNER JOIN`and will only return those rows where there is matching data in all tables; if you want to return rows for properties without tenants you should use`LEFT JOIN`instead.

also, the column`ten_name`seems to be duplicated between tenants and reports; maybe the latter table should have a column`tenant_id`instead?

Comment: @pradeepa Do you have data that can be joined in all tables? And to retrieve data for a specific property add `WHERE p.`property_name` = 'Property Name'` to the end of the query. This is really basic SQL, if you don't understand it fully maybe you should look at a beginner tutorial.

Comment: Hi @jpw, the above query was working fine, changed in the third line  p.`id` = sp.`prop_id`. Thank you

Comment: @pradeepa oh right, my bad, typed in the wrong column there.